# How to load a VC++ CLR library in MFC application?

Tags: c++, dll, mfc, visual-c++

HI I have a application developed in VC++6.0 ,now I want use some new features from .NET and developed a library, to develop this library I have to use the CLR-VC++ now I packaged this in a DLL.Now I need to call the routine of this DLL in my MFC application.

I tried to write a small MFC application to load this DLL, All the time the LoadLibrary() call is failing @err =126, module not found.I check the the dll with  dependency walker everthig is fine there. Please Help me in this regard.
If possible provide me a sample code or link.
Thanks in advance

-Sachin

Answer (score 1):

Use [ClrCreateManagedInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms230997.aspx) to create a COM-Callable-Wrapper for the object you want to call. Then use it like any other COM type.

Answer (score 1):

you have to go to property page -> Common properties ->Add New reference and include you 
CLR   Address there .

Answer (score -1):

I have a native C++ application which uses a managed C++ assembly and loads it with LoadLibrary() without problems. I had to do two things, however, before LoadLibrary() worked:

- Make sure that the current directory is the one where the managed assembly resides (use chdir() to change directory)
- In the managed assembly, the first function invoked by native code only defines the handler for `AppDomain::CurrentDomain->AssemblyResolve` event which explicitly loads assemblies from the folder of the managed application. It then invokes *another managed function* to do the rest of the initialization.

The reason for the last point is that CLR attempts to load an assembly dependency only if a function uses it. So I had to ensure that types in non-system assemblies are not referenced before the `AssemblyResolve` handler has been defined.

```
ref class AssemblyResolver
{
public:
    /// The path where the assemblies are searched
    property String^ Path
    {
        String^ get()
        { return path_; }
    }

    explicit AssemblyResolver(String^ path)
        : path_(path)
    { /* Void */ }

    Assembly^ ResolveHandler(Object^ sender, ResolveEventArgs^ args)    
    {
        // The name passed here contains other information as well
        String^ dll_name = args->Name->Substring(0, args->Name->IndexOf(','));
        String^ path = System::IO::Path::Combine(path_, dll_name+".dll");

        if ( File::Exists(path) )
            return Assembly::LoadFile(path);

        return nullptr;
    }

private:
    String^ path_;
};

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void Initialize()
{
    String^ path = "The path where the managed code resides";

    AssemblyResolver^ resolver = gcnew AssemblyResolver(path);
    AppDomain::CurrentDomain->AssemblyResolve += gcnew ResolveEventHandler(
        resolver, 
        &AssemblyResolver::ResolveHandler
    );

    FunctionWhichUsesOtherManagedTypes();
}
```